# Issues with Cython: compiled module not found when imported

Tags: python, cython

I'm having some trouble with cython. I recently found out about it and decided to use it in a project, but for some reason I'm unable to import the module/function that I've just compiled.

Here is what my `sum.pyx` file looks like:

```
def add(x, y):
    return x+y
```

And this is my `setup.py` file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(ext_modules = cythonize('image_converter.pyx'))
```

When I run `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`, the output shows this error:

```
Compiling sum.pyx because it changed.
[1/1] Cythonizing sum.pyx
C:\Users\User-name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:369: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: C:\Users\User-name\Documents\Cython\sum.pyx   
  tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
running build_ext
building 'sum' extension
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

Only one file was created called `sum.c`, but I'm aware that there should be some `.so` file created in a new directory but I couldn't find any, so I just continued and created the `test.py` file to see if the cython file worked:

```
import sum

print(sum.add(5,6))
```

But if I run this I get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sum'
```

I am using `Python 3.9.7` and `Visual Studio Code`, and I'm using the `g++` compiler (`MSYS2`).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) Why would `import sum` give `No module named 'image_converter'`? That makes no sense. 2) You won't get g++ build a Python module on Windows - it isn't a [supported compiler](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers). It used to be possible around  Python 3.4ish but isn't any more

Comment: @DavidW sorry about the first part, I was copying it from a different script which was called image_converter. So what compiler should I use instead of g++?

Comment: You should use a recent MSVC compiler - have a look at the link